# Add underscore before every upper case letter followed by lower case

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to add underscore before every capital letter followed by lower case. Here is the example:

```
cases <- c("XrefAcctnoAcctID", "NewXref1AcctID", "NewXref2AcctID", "ClientNo")
```

I have this:

```
[1] "XrefAcctnoAcctID" "NewXref1AcctID"  
[3] "NewXref2AcctID"   "ClientNo"
```

And I want to have this:

```
"xref_acctno_acct_id" 
"new_xref1_acct_id"   
"new_xref2_acct_id"    
"client_no"
```

I'm able to go this far:

```
> tolower(gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1_\\2", cases))
[1] "xref_acctno_acct_id" "new_xref1acct_id"   
[3] "new_xref2acct_id"    "client_no"
```

But `"new_xref1acct_id"` `"new_xref2acct_id"` does not reflect what I want.

Comment: Just change `[a-z]` to `[a-z0-9]` in your regex to match lowercase letters or numbers before the capital. Or change to `(.)([A-Z])` to match anything preceding a capital.

Answer (score 7):

We can use regex lookarounds to match the patterns that show a lowercase letter or a number followed by an upper case letter and replace it with `_`

```
tolower(gsub("(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])", "_", cases, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "xref_acctno_acct_id" "new_xref1_acct_id"   "new_xref2_acct_id"  
#[4] "client_no"
```

Or without lookarounds, we can capture the lower case or numbers as a group followed by upper case letter as another group and replace it with backreference for that group separated by `_`

```
tolower(gsub("([a-z1-9])([A-Z])", "\\1_\\2", cases))
#[1] "xref_acctno_acct_id" "new_xref1_acct_id"   "new_xref2_acct_id"  
#[4] "client_no"
```